# How to count instances of substring in elements of a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

This program creates a list from user input. Then, the user enters a substring to search for in the list. I want to count the instances that the substring appears in the list. For example: input_list = [python treeree three free]. search_str = 'ree'. Total should be 4.

I've tried this with the sum() function which got the correct result, but I need to do parse the list of words for a homework assignment.

```
total = 0
input_list = input('Type a list of words separated by a space: ')
search_str = str(input('Type a string to search for: '))
input_list = input_list.lower().split()
for x in input_list:
    if search_str in x:
        total = total + 1
print(search_str,": ",total)
```

The code runs, but, instead of counting the total instances that the string appears (i.e. 4), it only counts the number of elements in which it appears (i.e. 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed to use `count`, you could replace:

```
if search_str in x:
    total = total + 1
```

with:

```
total += x.count(search_str)
```

which will count all instances of `search_str` in `x`, giving your the result you expect.

Comment: It worked, Thierry! Thank you. I've selected you answer as the solution. For my edification, can you explain why the total wasn't working the way I had it?

Comment: I figured it out. I replaced my original if statement and total variable with 
total = x.count(search_str) + total, and now it has right count! I replaced + 1 with + total